# Классы в высоконагруженном проекте

Tags: php, highload

Вопрос к бывалым хайлодерам.
На серваке крутится react-php(демон).
Есть php класс, который используется как хранилище для 100500 параметров, которые могут поступить с запросом на сервак. У всех параметров есть значение по-умолчанию.
Есть варианты:

1. При поступлении запроса создать новый экземпляр класса, который умрёт сразу после того как сервер пошлёт ответ.
2. Создать один экземпляр данного класса. Реализовать ф-цию reset для сброса параметров на значение по-умолчанию при поступлении нового запроса. Заполнить класс данными которые поступают из запроса.

Какие могут быть преимущества или недостатки у каждого варианта?

Comment: Вопрос требует уточнения. Речь идет о демоне?

Comment: @Ruslan уточнил вопрос

Comment: И это уточнение меняет вопрос в корне и 2 ответа ниже можно смело удалять :( Для точного ответа на ваш вопрос нужно знать внутренности Реакта или попробовать самостоятельно создать тесты. Лично я не уверен, что знаю достаточно. Предположу, что первый вариант дешевле если много памяти и мало процессорного времени, второй вариант наоборот экономит память, но будет кушать процессор. Выбирать вам.

Comment: @Ruslan комментарий в ответ превратите

Comment: Я пишу ответ если абсолютно уверен в правильности своих суждений. Здесь я больше ориентируюсь на знания в которых не могу быть уверен на 100%. Если мой комментарий вам помог чем-то очень рад. Удачи в разработке.

Comment: В моем ответе разве что первые два предложения можно выкинуть. Микрооптимизациями следует заниматься только гениям. Пока у вас не HikariCP, об этом думать не надо.

Answer (score 1):

React.php пытается обрабатывать входящие запросы асинхронно, с использованием неблокирующего ввода/вывода. А это значит, что до момента, пока один запрос будет полностью обработан (а ответ отдан клиенту) процесс может *начать* обрабатывать еще несколько запросов. В целом, подход React.php очень напоминает подход node.js.

Если вы будете использовать второй метод (сбрасывать поля общего контекста), то все может закончится весьма плачевно. Например, вы не сможете согласовать заголовки запроса/ответа, если этот процесс будет хоть как-то завязан на контекст.

Единственно правильным в данной ситуации, будет создавать отдельный контекст для каждого запроса и убивать его, когда обработка запроса окончена и ответ отдан клиенту.

Answer (score 0):

PHP умирает по окончании каждого запроса. Ваш вопрос не имеет смысла, если только вы не используете полноценный демон. Даже в этом случае разницы особой нет, это не будет критически влиять на производительность, но лично я всегда выступаю за минимум статики и создавал бы для каждого запроса свой контекст.